# Dialog for choosing a percentage number in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

In my extended `PreferenceActivity` class I call `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.livewallpaper_settings)` so I have a xml file in which I define everything. How can I define a dialogue that asks the user to set a percentage? Maybe I could limit `EditTextPreference` to only accept values from 0-100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to handle this in code, not in XML.

1. Get the `EditText` of the `EditTextPreference` using
   [`getEditText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html#getEditText%28%29).
2. Set an `InputFilter` on it using [`setFilters()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFilters%28android.text.InputFilter%5B%5D%29)
3. Constrain the input in the [`filter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html#filter%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20android.text.Spanned,%20int,%20int%29) method of the
   `InputFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `SeekBarPreference` that pops up a dialog with a `SeekBar` in it, for the user to choose a percentage via a slider.

Comment: I think I'm gonna go with this(although the other answered my question), but it seems there is no inbuilt SeekBarPreference in the API. Should I copy it from androids internal source code? How come there are so few choices anyway? Basically just edittext, checkbox and list.

Comment: @Aron: "but it seems there is no inbuilt SeekBarPreference in the API" -- there's one floating around the AOSP source code. "How come there are so few choices anyway?" -- probably because it's not a very high priority, and because creating your own `DialogPreference` is not very difficult.